# @MAPSTRUCT. No property named "packaging" exists in source parameter(s)

Tags: java, spring, классы, dto, mapstruct

Я пишу `MVC` `Rest`-приложение. Использую `Spring` и `Hibernate`. Решил делать маппинг в `DTO` через `Mapstruct`. Кажется, я все делал по инструкции, но выдается ошибка. В чем проблема, я не могу понять. На форумах и в гугле очень мало информации.

P.S. Я не использую в данном случае `Ломбок`. Геттеры и Сеттеры прописаны вручную.

Drink:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "drink", schema = "public")
public class Drink {

    public Drink() { // Constructor for Hibernate

    }


    // Fields
    //
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private float price;

    @Column(name = "about")
    private String about;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    // Relationships
    //
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "packaging_id")
    private Packaging packaging;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Countries countries;
}
```

DrinkDTO:

```java
public class DrinkDTO {

    // Fields
    //
    private String drinkName;

    private float drinkPrice;

    private String drinkAbout;

    private Packaging drinkPackaging;

    private Manufacturer drinkManufacturer;

    private Countries drinkCountries;


    // Getters and Setters
    //
    public String getDrinkName() {
        return drinkName;
    }

    public void setDrinkName(String drinkName) {
        this.drinkName = drinkName;
    }

    public float getDrinkPrice() {
        return drinkPrice;
    }

    public void setDrinkPrice(float drinkPrice) {
        this.drinkPrice = drinkPrice;
    }

    public String getDrinkAbout() {
        return drinkAbout;
    }

    public void setDrinkAbout(String drinkAbout) {
        this.drinkAbout = drinkAbout;
    }

    public Packaging getDrinkPackaging() {
        return drinkPackaging;
    }

    public void setDrinkPackaging(Packaging drinkPackaging) {
        this.drinkPackaging = drinkPackaging;
    }

    public Manufacturer getDrinkManufacturer() {
        return drinkManufacturer;
    }

    public void setDrinkManufacturer(Manufacturer drinkManufacturer) {
        this.drinkManufacturer = drinkManufacturer;
    }

    public Countries getDrinkCountries() {
        return drinkCountries;
    }

    public void setDrinkCountries(Countries drinkCountries) {
        this.drinkCountries = drinkCountries;
    }

    // toSTRING
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DrinkDTO{" +
                "drinkName='" + drinkName + '\'' +
                ", drinkPrice=" + drinkPrice +
                ", drinkAbout='" + drinkAbout + '\'' +
                ", drinkPackaging=" + drinkPackaging +
                ", drinkManufacturer=" + drinkManufacturer +
                ", drinkCountries=" + drinkCountries +
                '}';
    }
```

CustomerController:

```java
@GetMapping("/drinks")
    List<DrinkDTO> getAllDrinks(){
        return DrinkMapper.INSTANCE.drinksToDrinksDTO(customerService.getAllDrinks());
    }
```

BUILD.GRADLE

```java
// Mapstruct
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
```

DrinkMapper:

```java
@Mapper
public interface DrinkMapper {

    DrinkMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DrinkMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "drinkName")
    @Mapping(source = "price", target = "drinkPrice")
    @Mapping(source = "about", target = "drinkAbout")
    @Mapping(source = "packaging", target = "drinkPackaging")
    @Mapping(source = "manufacturer", target = "drinkManufacturer")
    @Mapping(source = "countries", target = "drinkCountries")
    DrinkDTO drinkToDrinkDTO(Drink drink);

    @Mapping(source = "drinkName", target = "name")
    @Mapping(source = "drinkPrice", target = "price")
    @Mapping(source = "drinkAbout", target = "about")
    @Mapping(source = "drinkPackaging", target = "packaging")
    @Mapping(source = "manufacturer", target = "drinkManufacturer")
    @Mapping(source = "countries", target = "drinkCountries")
    Drink drinkDTOtoDrink(DrinkDTO drinkDTO);

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "drinkName")
    @Mapping(source = "price", target = "drinkPrice")
    @Mapping(source = "about", target = "drinkAbout")
    @Mapping(source = "packaging", target = "drinkPackaging")
    @Mapping(source = "manufacturer", target = "drinkManufacturer")
    @Mapping(source = "countries", target = "drinkCountries")
    List<DrinkDTO> drinksToDrinksDTO(List<Drink> drinks);
}
```

ERRORS:
[image]

Comment: Коллекции иным путем памятся https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для маппинга `drinkDTOtoDrink` необходимо поменять местами
   `manufacturer` и `drinkManufacturer`, `countries` и
   `drinkCountries`.
2. Для маппинга `drinksToDrinksDTO` не нужно
   перечислять маппинг полей. Вместо этого необходимо указать какой
   маппинг нужно использовать. В данном случае `drinkToDrinkDTO`.
3. Для маппинга `drinkDTOtoDrink` добавить игнорирование полей `id` и `deleted`

Вот исправленный код:

```
import org.mapstruct.*;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface DrinkMapper {

    DrinkMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DrinkMapper.class);

    @Named("drinkToDrinkDTO")
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "name", target = "drinkName"),
            @Mapping(source = "price", target = "drinkPrice"),
            @Mapping(source = "about", target = "drinkAbout"),
            @Mapping(source = "packaging", target = "drinkPackaging"),
            @Mapping(source = "manufacturer", target = "drinkManufacturer"),
            @Mapping(source = "countries", target = "drinkCountries")
    })
    DrinkDTO drinkToDrinkDTO(Drink drink);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "deleted", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(source = "drinkName", target = "name"),
            @Mapping(source = "drinkPrice", target = "price"),
            @Mapping(source = "drinkAbout", target = "about"),
            @Mapping(source = "drinkPackaging", target = "packaging"),
            @Mapping(source = "drinkManufacturer", target = "manufacturer"),
            @Mapping(source = "drinkCountries", target = "countries")
    })
    Drink drinkDTOtoDrink(DrinkDTO drinkDTO);

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "drinkToDrinkDTO")
    List<DrinkDTO> drinksToDrinksDTO(List<Drink> drinks);

}
```

Код небольшого теста:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class DrinkMapperTest {

    @Test
    void dto2entity() {
        DrinkDTO dto = new DrinkDTO();
        dto.setDrinkName("test");

        Drink entity =
                DrinkMapper.INSTANCE.drinkDTOtoDrink(dto);
        assertThat(entity).isNotNull();
        assertThat(entity.getName()).isEqualTo(dto.getDrinkName());
    }

    @Test
    void entity2dto() {
        Drink entity = new Drink();
        entity.setName("test");

        DrinkDTO dto =
                DrinkMapper.INSTANCE.drinkToDrinkDTO(entity);
        assertThat(dto).isNotNull();
        assertThat(dto.getDrinkName()).isEqualTo(entity.getName());
    }

    @Test
    void entityList2dtoList() {
        Drink entity = new Drink();
        entity.setName("test");

        List<Drink> entityList =
                Collections.singletonList(entity);

        List<DrinkDTO> dtoList =
                DrinkMapper.INSTANCE.drinksToDrinksDTO(
                        entityList);
        assertThat(dtoList).isNotNull();
        assertThat(dtoList).hasSize(1);
        assertThat(dtoList.get(0)).isNotNull();
        assertThat(dtoList.get(0).getDrinkName()).isEqualTo(entity.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Итог: ничего не поменялось. Все тоже самое!

Comment: @ArturVartanyan, тогда остается только проверить корректность getter-ов, setter-ов

Comment: Они автоматически созданы идейкой. Ошибок быть не может(